# Accessing std::vector more efficiently

Tags: c++, performance, vector

In my project, I am defining a class `Matrix` and the data structure that I am using is `std::vector<std::vector<T> > matrix;`

Now my question is: how can I access it more efficiently? If I remember correctly, accessing by index (e.g. matrix[i][j]) is an efficiency killer, while the advised way is via iterators. Is this right?

Assuming it is, then I have another problem: sometimes I need to know the index of the row or of the columns I am operating on. For instance, consider the addition element-by-element with another matrix: how can I say that

```
C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j]
```

without using two indexes `i` and `j`? Then I have other operations, like multiplication by a `Vector` (another class I am defining), but I guess if I understand correctly the most efficient way to access elements, then I can replicate the same pattern.

Comment: `matrix[i][j]` is not so bad.What's going to kill you is you have N+1 `std::vector`s [with no assurances of spatial locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_miss). If you want fast, go with a 1D vector and index it with row * numColumns + column. Note how a matrix class is defined here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op . It gets around a lot of the problems you will encounter. I recommend using a `std:: vector` in place of the dynamic array, though.

Comment: Accessing by index is not a problem by itself, the efficiency killer is accessing non-contiguous memory, doesn't matter how you do it or how you avoid it.

Comment: I see, then I will probably try with a 1D `std::vector` that contains `rows*columns` elements

Comment: Things will get more interesting when you get to matrix-matrix multiplication, because then it turns out the natural way to write it will iterate "the wrong way" over one of the matrices. There are tricks to get around that though.

Comment: @harold You mean because of the fact that you want to consider the columns of the second matrix and you find yourself "jumping" here and there in the second `vector`, right?

Comment: Wouldn't mind a link if you have one at hand, @harold . Always looking for ways to improve my code.

Comment: @user4581301 so many links, so hard to choose.. if you search for "matrix multiplication cache blocking" you should find all sorts of interesting articles/papers/etc. Benchmarks too.

Comment: Blocking. There's the keyword. Thank you, @harold !

Answer (score 2):

> how can I access it more efficiently? If I remember correctly, accessing by index (e.g. matrix[i][j]) is an efficiency killer, while the advised way is via iterators. Is this right?

Don't guess, read it up:

> **Complexity**
>
> Constant.
>
> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

As harold pointed out, that doesn't mean it's efficient, but knowing that this operator is (always?) implemented similar to...

```
// data member
T * underlying_array;
// in operator[]
return *(underlying_array + position); // underlying_array[position]
```

... this will be relatively good, performance wise. Though note that I also heard of STL implementations that add a bounds check to `operator[]`, which adds a branch and thus may impact performance negatively.

That said, you can of course change your code to use iterators instead of `operator[]`, for example:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> A,B,C;
// Check for correct sizes first!
auto a_row = std::begin(A);
auto c_row = std::begin(C);
auto b_row = std::begin(B);
for (; a_row != std::end(A); ++a_row, ++b_row, ++c_row) {
  // Check correct sizes!
  auto a_col = std::begin(*a_row);
  auto b_col = std::begin(*b_row);
  auto c_col = std::begin(*c_row);
  for (; a_col != std::end(*a_row); ++a_col, ++b_col, ++c_col) {
    *c_col = *a_col + *b_col;
  }
}
```

This *could* be more efficient ... but whether it's worth it ...

The **real** performance killer will be *if* your data isn't all stored contiguously. `std::vector` stores it's elements in contiguous memory, but storing `std::vector`s (as your "outer" vector does) contiguously doesn't help you, because the "inner" vectors may store their data at different places. Thus, to keep all data of your matrices in contiguous memory, you should use a single `std::vector` and do the correct column - row indexing yourself (your matrix can provide `operator[]` returning a reference to an instance of a helper class which in turn implements its `operator[]` to access the matrix, making calls like `matrix[1][2]` possible).

Comment: "complexity: constant" - that doesn't make it efficient. It turns out it is, but that quote doesn't prove it.

Comment: OK, then I will probably switch to using a 1D vector in order to access contiguous memory. Or do you have another way to suggest?

Comment: @harold Indeed, I was assuming OP confused it with random access in say a list. Will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation for std::vector

> **The elements are stored contiguously**, which means that elements can be
>   accessed not only through iterators, **but also using offsets on regular
>   pointers to elements.**

So, it should be similar to accessing from an array, which should be efficient.

Also, the random access of elements in a vector is a constant and does not depend on size of the vector.*O(1)*. You can also use it like getting the underlying array of an vector and access it, but that should be the same as using random access..

```
int main()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;

   matrix.push_back({1,2,3});
   matrix.push_back({1,2,3});
   matrix.push_back({1,2,3});

   int op = matrix.data()[0][0] + matrix.data()[0][1];

   std::cout << "OP should be 3 : Real op" << op << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: One vector is contiguous. The odds of two being contiguous is low. The odds of 10 staggeringly low. So in vector<vector<T>> every time you switch between rows (or columns if that's how you roll) there will likely be a performance hit. Accessing from `vec[0][0]` to `vec[0][1]` to `vec[0][2]` is a piece of cake, but `vec[0][2]` to `vec[1][0]` may cost you because you just switched `vector`s.

Answer (score 0):

> In my project, I am defining a class `Matrix` and the data structure
>   that I am using is `std::vector<std::vector<T> > matrix;`
>
> Now my question is: how can I access it more efficiently?

Measure its current speed and measure it again when you have modified the code. This will tell you if there's any measurable improvement at all.

You can **try** to improve performance by storing the data as a simple `std::vector<T>` of size *width x height* and calculate the offset accordingly when given x and y.

For example (just to get across the concept, no error checking or anything):

```
// ...

private:
    int width;
    std::vector<T> v;

// ...

public:

    Matrix(int width, int height) : width(width), v(width * height)
    {
    }

    T get(int x, int y) const
    {
        return v[(y * width) + x];
    }

// ...
```

But chances are that your machine is too fast and your data is too small to see any difference.

Comment: Actually I am using matrices of several thousands of elements, so there may be a difference. Anyway I will try